# Always Cleaning / Building Project on Debug

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a rather large solution of about 20 projects, that I have worked with for about three years now.  In recent weeks, I seemed to have lost the ability to just press "Run and Debug" on my toolbar.  If I do this, I lose all ability to debug and use breakpoints.  My breakpoints all get a little yellow exclamation point on them and never run.  Below is an example.

[image]

To fix this so I can get debugging again I have to fully clean the project.  If I try to run after cleaning, i get an error saying the file does not exist. So I have to then fully re-build the project before I can run.  It works just once, and then I lose my ability to debug again.  Below is the error if I don't manually build first:

[image]

This seems to be effecting several (maybe all) projects in my solution and is causing extremely large problems for me.  Some of my projects I need to breakpoints to verify data before it runs, and if I forget to do this, it runs before verifying.

Any help in fixing this would be amazing.  Under solution settings, my start up project i set to "Current Selection" if that helps.

**UPDATE:**
So far under solution settings -> configuration a bunch of my items had "Build" not selected for Debug.  Not sure how that happened, but updating that for now seems to have solved it.  If it goes to not building each time again I will re-update, but for now I think that solved the issue.

Comment: If you right click on your solution and select Configuration Manager, is the build box checked for all your projects?

Comment: its selected as "Current Selection" however i did have in the past multiple startup projects and even though that option was not checked,  under the list of projects i had some selected. I just deselected them and seems to be the same

Comment: Changing the startup project from "Current selection" to "Single startup" seems to have solved the issue for now.  However with so many projects this can be a pretty big inconvenience too. At least it's running in debug though.  Hope that helps if anyone has the same issue or knows how to solve for that.

Comment: Actually it worked for a few builds now does not again... so that did not help either

Comment: This the second question about disappearing EXE files this week, it rains it poors.  Sounds like some virus scanner product got updated.

Comment: possibly. The issue was that somehow the exes were not set to build on DEBUG for some reason. half of my project files in the solution were not checked, so re-checking them solved it.  Might be from when I installed AVAST lately